# JPA hibernate date between query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

In my application am using JPA entity manager to persist data/fetch data.

```
em.executeQuery("select * from file_calender_mapping where start_date between :start and :end");
```

em.setParameter("start",startDate)//startDate is an date object

em.setParameter("end",endDate)//endDate is an date object

List fmlist=em.execute();

The proble is just like this,

```
"select * from file_calender_mapping where start_date between start and end"
```

when am passing some date as start= "2011-08-03 05:08:00",and end="2011-08-04 06:08:00"
then the mysql return one row having the start time ="2011-08-03 05:30:00",its good,But 
when my application executing such query it dose not returning any row.Actually what i have seen that my application returning value for two different date,but not for same date different time,thats the main problem.
One another thing is my "start" field for Table "file_calender_mapping" datatype is "timestamp".

So what i was thinking that ther may be some problem on JPA/Hibernate

Comment: Can you confirm you're using java.util.Date and not java.sql.Date? Could you add the relevant bits of the class file_calender_mapping (is that a real class name?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to specify the exact types of parameters as follows:

```
em.setParameter("start", startDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
em.setParameter("end",endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the strong feeling that you're confusing EntityManager.createQuery() with EntityManager.createNativeQuery() and you're somehow capturing all the exceptions, which somehow makes you don't receive anything back.

I'm assuming that, because I don't think you have a class named file_calender_mapping.

#### edit

The [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html) will explain it better than I do, but a JPA QL query is transformed to the navite sql of the DB using the mapping, while a native query is send as it's to the DB.
Again, I suggest you to read the documentation, it's quite useful.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the difference between  EntityManager.createQuery() and EntityManager.createNativeQuery()